# SwiftUI Running a Method Call when Bindable property changes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am struggling to understand how to run a method when a Bindable object changes. Here is the code I have so far:
[image]

However, for some reason, the fetchFoods method never gets called as a result of searchText changing and I can't seem to understand why.

Answer (score 2):

@Harish @Asperi you're making confusion here guys. There's a specific reason why @Harish's method doesn't get called. Let's create a simple example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = "" {
        didSet {
            print("Triggered!")
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Type something...", text: $text)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

If you copy paste and run this minimum viable example you'll see that the string "Triggered!" will never get printed. And this is because what you are changing **through the $ binding** is not the `text` property, but the **binding wrapped value** accessed through the `$` sign. They are two completely different things. This is really important to understand.

So, why does the @Asperi's example work? (I slightly simplified it to create another minimum viable example):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isOn = false {
        didSet {
            print("Triggered!")
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        Button(
            action: { self.isOn.toggle() },
            label: { Text(self.isOn ? "Hide" : "Show") }
        )
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

This time if you copy paste this code you'll see that "Triggered!" will get printed. And this is fine because tapping on the button you're changing exactly `self.isOn`. This time you're not using any `$` sign to access the binding wrapped value.

The examples here above seems using the same approach, but actually they are really different. And again, it's really important to understand this difference. So, how can you get what you want (i.e. "to run a method when a Bindable object changes")? You must rely on a `ViewModel` and on a `@Published` property wrapper:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = "" {
        didSet {
            print("Triggered!")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Type something...", text: $viewModel.text)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Which are meant exactly for that:

> Combine's Published property wrapper is similar in spirit [to the other property wrappers], allowing
>   clients to subscribe to @Published properties (via the $ projection)
>   **to receive updates when the value changes**.

From https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md